# Updating Values with C# in SQL Table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview

I was wondering if it is possible for the update button to save the changes made in the table. I wrote this code but I have no idea how it could possibly work

This is the code i wrote for the update button:

```
string conString = "Data Source=MIRANDA-PC;Initial Catalog=Futebol do Rosa;Integrated Security=True";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
string selectSql = "Update Players$ set Player Name='" + dataGridView2.Text + "";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSql, con);
con.Open();
```

This is the table I want to update the values in:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Well, you just need to execute your query with [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

But more important, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.

And if your table or column names more than one word, you need to use them with `[]` as `[Player Name]`. And honestly, it is a little bit weird to use `$` sign in a table name.

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "Update Players$ set [Player Name] = @name";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 16).Value = dataGridView2.Text;
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to execute your SQL query with your db object.

```
dbinstance.ExecuteSqlCommand(string sqlcommand, object[] params);
```

This method is both for DDL and DML.
you can also use ExecuteNonQuery method.

Answer (score 0):

```
 cmd.CommandText = "Update Players$ set [Player Name] = @Playername";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Playername", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 16).Value = dataGridView2.Text;
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution (if possible) to to convert your DAL (Data Access Layer) to Entity-framework based, instead of writing your own SQL queries. This is safe-by-design and never is vulnerable to SQL Injection of any kind.
Here is some mockup code:

```
using (AppEntities currDb = new AppEntities)
{
    Players PlayerToEdit =
    from player in currDb.Players
    where player.PlayerID == lngPlayerID
    select player.First();

    PlayerToEdit.PlayerName = dataGridView2.Text;
    currDb.SaveChanges();
}
```

You can read about it some more here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx